# Inject into child class, from parent that has constructor parameters. (Aurelia)

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia, webpack-dev-server

I am working with Aurelia and trying to achieve injection in the following way.

I have a parent class that requires a setting object on construction.
I derive from that class with a child and want to inject a service into that class:

```
export class parent
{
  constructor(aParam)
  {
    this.Something = aParam;
  }
}

@inject(service)
export class child extends parent
{
  constructor(aParam, aService)
  {
    super(aParam);
    this.Service = aService;
  }
}
```

Now I want to be able to construct the child class the same as the parent class e.g.:

```
const Parent = new parent(10);
const Child = new child(10);
```

My question is, how can I achieve this?

I use Aurelia framework, with webpack to generate my javascript.
Any help would be appreciated, the only things I found so far are:
https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/11/injection-inheritance-aurelia/
But this only solves the case if the parent also injects something.

Regards,
Jan Jaap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the instance of `service` directly from Aurelia's dependency injection container. This is the same as the "normal" injection code (`@inject(service)...`):

```
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection’;

export class child extends parent
{
  constructor(aParam)
  {
    super(aParam);
    this.Service = Container.instance.get(service);;
  }
}
```